# Составление схемы предложения и выделение грамматических основ

Tags: члены-предложения, синтаксический-разбор

> Князь Андрей, думавший, что ему было все равно, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так, как взяли Смоленск, внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло.

Схема: `[..., (что...), ...]`

Грамматические основы:

- *"князь остановился"*
- *"было всё равно"*
- *"взяли Смоленск"*

Правильно ли составлена схема предложения и выделены грамматические основы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом предложении три придаточных:

[…, (…), (ли…), (как…), ...]

Answer (score 4):

Схема: [..., (что...), (ли...так) (как...) ...]. Последовательное подчинение двух изъяснительных и одного обстоятельственного предложений.